# Selected option in selectbox issue

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-select2

I'm facing an anoying issue in Firefox (in other browsers like: Chrome, Opera, Edge everything works well). The problem is that Firefox does not select option with the **selected** attribute. When I hit **ctrl+F5** the option is selected properly. But of course I can't leave it like that.

I've tried following:

1. Added `autocomplete="off"` to each option.
2. Put the select to the form with name.
3. Tried with `selected` `selected="selected"` `selected=""`

Code sample:

```
<select class="form-control" id="schoolChooser" style="width:100%">
      @foreach($user_schools as $user_school)
        <option value="{{$user_school->id}}" autocomplete="off"
          @if($school_id == $user_school->id)
            selected
          @endif
          >{{$user_school->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Can you share an MCVE?

Comment: Okay, now it's visible.

Comment: what is the version of FF ?

Comment: FF version - 54.0